# How to recover the chat log of a deleted Skype contact?

Tags: skype, history, logging

I recently deleted a contact on Skype, but I think the chat is probably on the harddrive.

How do you recover chat log/history for contacts that you have deleted on Skype?

Answer (score 1):

StudioHack covered the location.

I recently moved my chat history and from what I saw in the file, it was plain-text, but very much a mess of mostly random text. You might need to re-add the contacts and import the chat history to make it easily readable.

I'm sure you could pick out the parts you want if you're looking for something specific, but the chat history file contains the chat history/dates/times for every contact in your Skype. It's not seperated per contact, like in, say, Windows Live Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

See this forum: [Move Skype History From Windows XP To Windows 7](http://www.question-defense.com/2010/01/12/move-skype-history-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7)

Your chat history can be found in:

- Windows Vista/7: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Skype`
- Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Skype`

More file locations, etc found in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use SkypeLogView to access the Skype database file (main.db) and view the message. Download and install SkypeLogView> Launch the application on your computer, then open the main.db file> Use the SkypeLogView browser to find the dialog containing the deleted message.
The main.db file is stored in the location: C:\ Users \ YourWindowsUsername \ AppData \ Roaming \ Skype \ YourSkypeUsername

Second, use the Windows Data Recovery tool to recover deleted Skype messages.